# Cantillation of the last chapter of Shema

Tags: shema, trop-cantillation

It just caught my eyes that in the Artscroll siddur I use in the synagogue writes [Bemidbar 15:39](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0415.htm#39) the following way:

> וְהָיָ֣ה לָכֶם֮ לְצִיצִת֒ וּרְאִיתֶ֣ם אֹת֗וֹ וּזְכַרְתֶּם֙ אֶת־כָּל־מִצְוֺ֣ת יְהוָ֔ה וַֽעֲשִׂיתֶ֖ם אֹתָ֑ם **וְלֹֽא־תָת֜וּרוּ** אַֽחֲרֵ֤י לְבַבְכֶם֙ וְאַֽחֲרֵ֣י עֵֽינֵיכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁר־אַתֶּ֥ם זֹנִ֖ים אַֽחֲרֵיהֶֽם׃
>
> And it shall be unto you for a fringe, that ye may look upon it, and remember all the commandments of *Hashem,* and do them; **and that ye go not about** after your own heart and your own eyes, after which ye use to go astray.

Almost in all other siddurim and chumashim I know there is a [kadma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kadma_(trope)) on the word ולא. I found it this way in [R' Heidenheim's](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&st=&pgnum=50) siddur, but [R' Emden](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001167350/NLI) (p. 253) seems to omit the *kadma* as well. [Mechon Mamre](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0404.htm), [Mikraot Gedolot haKeter](https://www.mgketer.org/mikra/4/15), [R' Yellin's chumash](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Yellin_Tanakh.pdf/page87-1239px-Yellin_Tanakh.pdf.jpg) and the [Leningrad Codex](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/Leningrad_Codex_FULL.pdf/page174-1275px-Leningrad_Codex_FULL.pdf.jpg) (seemingly) support the version without *kadma,* yet Koren and my older Artscroll siddur both write it with *kadma.* Are there any rabbinical sources discussing this issue?

Comment: When you ask "Are there any rabbinical sources discussing this issue?" do you mean "Can someone list for me every rabbi or publisher who mentinoed an opinion on the matter?"? If so please edit to clarify. If you want in depth discussions of the justifications for the alternatives, edit to say so. Just clarify what you want. Right now this is technically a yes/no question.

Comment: https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=43300

Comment: FWIW - I've viewed 3 different *Tikkunim* and all use the *azla geresh* as you have placed in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ולא תתורו: kadma veazla or azla-geresh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/122087/%d7%95%d7%9c%d7%90-%d7%aa%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%95-kadma-veazla-or-azla-geresh)

Comment: Kazi bácsi, Koren follows R' Wolf Heidenheim, in general, when it comes to mesorat Tana"ch (one tell-tale example is the more frequent usage of chataf patach, rather than sheva')

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't have Koren books at hand, but I clearly remember that they don't write הַֽלְלוּיָהּ & co. with chataf.

Comment: For close voters: my question clearly asks rabbinical sources (like Minchat Shai that we don't have here) arguing the correctness of either of the versions.