# ולא תתורו: kadma veazla or azla-geresh?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, shema, mesorah-tradition, trop-cantillation

In the third parashah of Shema' (maftir from P' Shelach) we have a divergence of cantillation on the words ולא תתורו. In R' Wolf Heidenheim (see Koren for a contempary example) these words are cantillated with kadma veazla (ול֨א תת֜ורו) whereas in Breuer (Keter Yerushalayim) they are tied together and vocalised with an azla-geresh (ולא־תת֜ורו).

What is the mesorah of these two variants ?

Comment: "What is the mesorah of these two variants?" What does this mean? I don't know what you are asking. Please be more precise

Comment: Duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111989/15256

Comment: As a Sepharadi who witnesses chazanim read it with a Kadma veAzla daily even though the siddurim we commonly use do not have that, I'm very happy you posed this question.

Answer (score 6):

All the [Tiberian](https://manuscripts.sefaria.org/leningrad-color/BIB_LENCDX_F085A.jpg) [manuscripts](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33644&st=&pgnum=11) (and [here](https://www.wdl.org/en/item/11364/view/1/315/), [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Tanakh-Sassoon1053-04-Numbers.pdf/page15-1754px-Tanakh-Sassoon1053-04-Numbers.pdf.jpg), [here](https://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=or_4445_fs001r), and [here](https://digi.vatlib.it/view/MSS_Vat.ebr.448)) and the majority of the other (Ashkenazi/Sephardi) old manuscripts<sup>*</sup> have a maqef, followed by the [Venice Mikraot Gedolot](https://archive.org/details/mikraot_gdolot/Torah/page/n343/mode/2up) and other historically important printed editions.

The testimony to no maqef consists of a handful of old Ashkenazi manuscripts<sup>*</sup>, followed by some printed editions in the last 150 years or so.

Suffice to say that the weight of evidence is on the side of the maqef.

---

<sup>*</sup> See a fuller list of manuscripts [here](http://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=34428), with the key [here](https://simla.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=67528) (PDF downloads).